# <h:commandButton actionListener not operating

Tags: java, html, primefaces

I have a "multipart/form-data" in which i compine text and file uploading. The problem is that the submit button does not work at all.I am using NetBeans 8.2, Glassfish server 4.1, Primefaces latest edition Below is my code:

```
<h:form enctype="multipart/form-data">   
        <p:panelGrid columns="2">    
            Model
            <p:inputText value="#{guitarBean.model}"/>
            Image
            <p:fileUpload rendered="true" value="#{addBean.img}" mode="advanced" auto="true" allowTypes="/(\.|\/)(gif|jpe?g|png)$/" sizeLimit="100000" />
            <h:commandButton value="Submit" actionListener="#{addBean.store()}" />       
        </p:panelGrid>
    </h:form>
```

Here is my config file:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
    <param-value>Development</param-value>
</context-param>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>DisplayImage</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>utilities.DisplayImage</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>DisplayImage</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/DisplayImage</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<session-config>
    <session-timeout>
        30
    </session-timeout>
</session-config>
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>faces/index.xhtml</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

And below are my bean files:

```
public class GuitarBean implements Serializable {

 private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
 private String model;
 @Lob
 private byte[] img;
 //getters and setters
```

addBean:

```
public class AddBean implements Serializable{

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Inject GuitarBean guitarBean;

private UploadedFile img;
/getters setters
public void store(){

    if(img!=null){
        try{

            InputStream fin = img.getInputstream();
            ps.setString(1, guitarBean.getModel());
            ps.setBinaryStream(2, fin, img.getSize());
            ps.executeUpdate();
            //catch etc....
```

Comment: please read my answer about this question [How to upload a file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39486157/get-uploaded-file-path-in-primefaces/39487964#39487964), and does it enter to the method store ?

Comment: in case you are using a maven project it can only be caused by dependecies (you forget to put them in the WAR+ the EJB) if no you are fogetting something in the web.xml the post that i provide is enough to solve the problem (or the library that you use )